# Anonymous delegates in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, delegates, foreach, scope, anonymous-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about foreach and delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600597/question-about-foreach-and-delegates)

I would like to know what phenomenon is going on here:

Converting a `List<string>` into a list of delegates returning that same string goes wrong.

This happens in `WrongConversion` when I work directly with the variable that is returned by the `foreach` over the input list.  (the *last string in the list* is returned each time)

In the `CorrectConversion`, I first assign a local variable and use that in the delegate.

This assignment seems superfluous at first.

Input:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Program
{
  delegate string StringReturner();

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
    Display(WrongConversion(list));
    Display(CorrectConversion(list));
    System.Console.ReadKey();
  }
  static List<StringReturner> WrongConversion(List<string> list)
  {
    var result = new List<StringReturner>();
    foreach (var s in list)
    {
      result.Add(() => { return s; });  // <========= s is always "c" ?
    }
    return result;
  }
  static List<StringReturner> CorrectConversion(List<string> list)
  {
    var result = new List<StringReturner>();
    foreach (var s in list)
    {
      var localString = s;              // <========= What happens here?
      result.Add(() => { return localString; });
    }
    return result;
  }
  private static void Display(List<StringReturner> list)
  {
    foreach (var stringReturner in list)
      System.Console.Write(stringReturner());
    System.Console.WriteLine();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
ccc
abc
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of a million questions. It has to do with closing over the local variable.

Answer (score -2):

This is a known "bug" in C# (VB.NET too I think). The simple answer is that the localString variable you create is scoped inside the foreach, therefore a new copy of it is used for each itteration, however in the other case you simply reference s, which ultimately ends up beeing c (before you print it at least). To "resolve" issues of this kind I've made it a practice to do

```
foreach(var _s = ....) {
    var s = _s;
    /* code here that uses s */
}
```

every time I have use for delegates like that.

Comment: This is also a known issue to the StackOverflow community. Thus, close as duplicate.